# Innobyte plugin issue: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: mysql, magento, constraints, integrity

When I'm trying to save a product in Magento I receive this issue:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`papet_mag`.`innobyte_emag_marketplace_product_cat_characteristic`,
>   CONSTRAINT `FK_FC8B248E7E23F0E4DAEC8D31641C9910` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`product_id`) REFERENCES `innobyte_emag_marketplace_category_c)

query was:

```
INSERT INTO `innobyte_emag_marketplace_product_cat_characteristic` (`product_id`,`characteristic_id`,`value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?)
```

What can I do to resolve it ? This is new for me. This issue appear recently

Comment: how did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The message seems pretty clear to me:

- You are trying to insert a row into the table `innobyte_emag_marketplace_product_cat_characteristic` with a `product_id` that doesn't exist in the referenced table `innobyte_emag_marketplace_category_c`.

The question is: What's the specific `product_id`, and does it actually exist?